# Image not attaching In Massaging Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send MMS through My Application But attachment of  Image is not working In HTC device. My code is :

```
    Intent inten = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        inten.setClassName("com.android.mms",com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity);
        inten.setType("image/*");
        inten.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File(Path)));
        startActivity(inten);
```

And I have Searched applications through wich I can send Image. By this code:

```
    Intent sendOption = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendOption.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> ris = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
            sendOption, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    for (ResolveInfo ri : ris) 
    {
        String appname = (String) ri.loadLabel(getPackageManager());
        String packagename = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        String classname = ri.activityInfo.name;

            Share.add(appname);
            Classname.add(classname);
            Packagename.add(packagename);
    }
```

But Massaging Application name is not coming in that list. This problem is in HTC . I have tasted in Samsung and Micromax in this it's working I have searched But not Getting Any proper Answer. There is to Many Question Having Same problem

Answer (score 1):

The following code work for me.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi how are you");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/file.gif")));
intent.setType("image/gif"); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send"));
```

Comment: have u tested it with HTC device. and you creating chooser also.

Comment: works on my HTC Desire (Froyo 2.2) and Galaxy Nexus (ICS 4.1.2) and Micromax A90S(4.0.4)

Comment: Here in your code you can fixed this intent class like 'inten.setClassName("com.android.mms",com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity);' and this problem is device specific. I found this problem in SAMSUNG Tab 2 and same code runs successfully in HTC ,SAMSUNG PHONE devices. This is due to Android OS code customization according to their needs. The class which you are calling may not exist in Specific Device based android OS.

Comment: Is your Image file path is correct? Where u pickup this image?